# R: how to count/sum preceding values for certain ID?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df1 with information on the number of acquisitions that a company has made during a certain year. I would need to

a) construct a dummy variable if there are observations available three consecutive  preceding years for each company each year

b) if there are three consecutive preceding years for that company-year, then sum the number of acquisitions made during that three-year period

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('XXXX-1999','XXXX-2000', 'XXXX-2001', 'YYYY-1999', 
'YYYY-2000', 'ZZZZ-1999','ZZZZ-2000','ZZZZ-2001', 'ZZZZ-2002'),
              No.of.Transactions=c(1,0,2,2,2,4,1,0,3))
```

where ID is the observation for a company during a year. The desired output is below

```
# Desired output
# ID | No.of.Transactions | 3 preceding yrs available dummy? | 
No.of.Transactions during 3 preceding yrs
# XXXX-1999 1 0 N/A
# XXXX-2000 0 0 N/A
# XXXX-2001 2 1 3
# YYYY-1999 2 0 N/A
# YYYY-2000 2 0 N/A
# ZZZZ-1999 4 0 N/A
# ZZZZ-2000 1 0 N/A
# ZZZZ-2001 0 1 5
# ZZZZ-2002 3 1 4
```

So if the "3 preceding yrs available dummy?" column takes a value of 1, then the final column should sum up all the transactions for the company during the focal and two preceding years.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why is the last line `# ZZZZ-2002 3 1 8`?  Shouldn't it be `# ZZZZ-2002 3 1 4`?  And do you mind if the `ID` column is split into `company` and `year`?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct, i made the edit now in the original post. I don't mind if the ID column is split into company and year, if that makes it easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?  I'm not overly happy with the `three_year_trans = trans + lag(trans, 1) + lag(trans, 2)` bit, but it's the best I've got off the top of my head.

In case it's not obvious, the `lag(year, 2, default = 0) == year - 2` bit ensures there are no missing years (for example, if company `XXXX` had `XXXX-1999`,  `XXXX-2001`, `XXXX-2002`, there'd be no totals for 2002, as 2000 is missing.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- data.frame(ID=c('XXXX-1999','XXXX-2000', 'XXXX-2001', 'YYYY-1999', 
                       'YYYY-2000', 'ZZZZ-1999','ZZZZ-2000','ZZZZ-2001', 'ZZZZ-2002'),
                  trans=c(1,0,2,2,2,4,1,0,3))

df1 %>%
  separate(ID, c("company", "year"), "-") %>% 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year)) %>% 
  group_by(company) %>% 
  arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(three_years_available = (lag(year, 2, default = 0) == year - 2) + 0,
         three_year_trans = if_else(three_years_available == 1,
                                    trans + lag(trans, 1) + lag(trans, 2),
                                    NA_real_)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(company, year)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of `ave` and `zoo::rollsumr`.  If you still need the dummy variable you could easily create it from the transaction sum variable.

```
library(zoo)
df1$trans.sum <- with(df1, ave(No.of.Transactions, sub("(^.{4}).*", "\\1", ID), 
                           FUN = function(x) rollsumr(x, 3, fill = NA)))
df1
         ID No.of.Transactions trans.sum
1 XXXX-1999                  1        NA
2 XXXX-2000                  0        NA
3 XXXX-2001                  2         3
4 YYYY-1999                  2        NA
5 YYYY-2000                  2        NA
6 ZZZZ-1999                  4        NA
7 ZZZZ-2000                  1        NA
8 ZZZZ-2001                  0         5
9 ZZZZ-2002                  3         4
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution was very straight-forward and did the trick!